# Wifi signal strength jumping to full, speed to near 0

Tags: networking, wireless, broadcom, macbook-pro

Frequently when using Ubuntu on my computer (a MacBook Pro 9,1), I will see the Wi-Fi signal strength indicator suddenly jump to full strength (it's usually less than that from where I work). At the same time as this happens, the speed of the connection drops to near zero (it's still connected, but it's slower than dial-up and most requests time out). It remains in this state until I click the network name in the menu to reset the connection, at which point the apparent signal strength drops back down and the speed back up to normal.

This happens frequently enough while using the computer that it makes it impractical to use. It started happening after upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10 and has persisted into 16.04. It has happened while connected to multiple different networks and does not happen when booted into other operating systems.

I've done a fair amount of searching and found nothing regarding this strange set of symptoms. I was hoping someone here might have a better idea what's going on as I'm fairly perplexed.

The output of the network diagnostic script is here: https://gist.github.com/duke9509/7c92461f7b29c3103ec87b1dee26a3f3

Answer (score 0):

You have installed a wrong driver. Connect to the internet by wire and run

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

Comment: Switched drivers. Honestly it got worse. Now resetting the connection no longer works and I have to just wait for it to stabilize on its own. Searching by wireless chip name and not "MacBook" finds a few more people having this or similar problems with the BCM4331 but no real solutions.

Comment: Well, there are two drivers that support this adapter. There is nothing else that can be done. This is because Broadcom poorly supports linux drivers.